# Should I use promise for mkdir

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I use the bluebird magic

```
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
```

and use

```
fs.readdirAsync(dest).then(function (val) {
        return val;
}).then(function (file) {

...
```

My question is for the following code (which is working) should I use the same and how 
I am talking about the `mkdir` function.

```
function createDir(folder) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (typeof require.cache.per === 'undefined') {
            require.cache.per = {};
            require.cache.per.mk = false;
        }
        if (!require.cache.per.mk) {
            fs.mkdir(folder, function (e) {
                if (!!e && e.code !== 'EEXIST') {
                    console.log('Error to create  folder: ' + err);
                }
                require.cache.per.mk = true;
                next();
            });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    };
}
```

My Question is should I use promise here or not, **what is recommended** ?
The code is working as expected...

Comment: You can just use `mkdirAsync`, promisifyAll creates it for you.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum -Thanks but how should I call it with the catch and the next inside promise ,can you please provide example?

Comment: Exactly the same way you did for `readdir`

Comment: it is recommended to use promise for an async call. so use the same way that used for readdir

Comment: That must be your choice. If u want use it - go ahead, if u OK with callbacks - ok :). Btw what the reason using `!!e` :) ?

Comment: @loadaverage `!!` is used to boolean-ify a value (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: @souldzin yep, I know. But if error `(e)` is exists then `!!e` doesn't make any sense coz it anyway `true`, otherwise if there are no error and `e` is `null` - `!!e`  means false (just like `null` means) and doesn't affect if..else statement.

Comment: @loadaverage oh yeah, it's pointless in this case, but sometimes it's just fun to use `!!` ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Promise simplifies, and unifies the interface. Either `.promisify()` or `.promisifyAll()` will do the trick.

Then you can chain everything like this:

```
fs.mkdir(dir)
    .then(function success(dir) {
        ...
    })
    .catch(function failure(err) {
        ...
    })
    .finally(function () {
    });
```

However in `node.js`, the most important thing is to NOT block the I/O. It doesn't  matter whether you use a Promise or a regular async/callback, as long as it's not blocking the main thread.

It's ok to have synchronous code in script that you want to run in shell, but for regular applications you should never use blocking I/O operations on purpose.

Comment: I totally agree, IMHO promises provide much better readability and maintainability for the code which proves important in team collaboration

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely update your code to be consistent. If possible, call `mkdirAsync` instead of `mkdir`

Example (from OP's code):

```
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

// ...

fs.mkdirAsync(folder)
   .catch({ code: 'EEXIST' }, function(e){
       // don't care about this error code  
   })
   .catch(function(e) {
       console.log('Error to create  folder: ' + e);
   })
   .then(function(){
       require.cache.per.mk = true;
       next();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

return fs.mkdirAsync(dir1)
  .then(function() {
    return fs.mkdirAsync(dir2);
  })
  .then(function() {
    return fs.mkdirAsync(dir3);
  })
```

Hope this helps.